# URL fragments (hash) append to page title automatically

Tags: google-analytics, internet-explorer, google-tag-manager

I am facing an issue (in IE): my url fragments (hash) will automatically add to the page title in my pageview (dt), but it only happens in IE.

I have used the `setTimeout` as below, but the pageview still has fragments in the title, but the virtual pageview will not have this issue, yeah, only the first pageview.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      window.document.title = MetaData.meta.title;
   }, 1000);
});
```

I am trying to determine if I can overwrite the default page title value in pageview or not. If it can, how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to overwrite the page title. You just need to write a JS function to parse the title string (eg. split by #) and then to return that value into the "title" field in GTM:

[image]

Comment: if you want to overwrite the `page path` value you can do it similarly by setting the field `page` to the value of a custom JS function from GTM